# Polly handle response and check status code

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, polly

I creating a list of Tasks and executing them with Task.WhenAll(). If an http request returns error status I want to retry the call.

I'm getting and error on this line: `ExecuteAsync(() => func()));`

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.HttpWebResponse>'

I know what the error means, but the part I need help with is the overall implementation of  Polly with parallel http calls and checking the response status.

Code:

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

var policy = Policy
                .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
                .OrResult<HttpWebResponse>(a => a.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync(i => pauseBetweenFailures);

var urls = new List<string>();

foreach (var mediaItem in UploadedMediaItems)
{
    var mediaRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("****"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        Headers = {
                { "id-token", id_Token },
                { "access-token", access_Token }
            }
    };

    async Task<string> func()
    {
        var response = await client.SendAsync(mediaRequest);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    tasks.Add(policy.ExecuteAsync(() => func()));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

foreach (var t in tasks)
{
    var postResponse = await t;
    urls.Add(postResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding any other issues (conceptual or otherwise)

You have the wrong generic parameter `HttpWebResponse`, it should be `HttpResponseMessage` as that is what `SendAsync` returns

```
var policy = Policy
   .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
   .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(a => a.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
   ...
```

Also, seemingly you would want to apply the *policy* to the `SendAsync` method, not the local method that returns a `Task<string>`

```
async Task<string> func()
{
   var response = await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => client.SendAsync(mediaRequest));
   return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
tasks.Add(func());
```

Also note, that you will need to recreate a new `HttpRequestMessage` for every retry. They cannot be reused.

Which may look more like this

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> Send()
{
   var mediaRequest = new HttpRequestMessage {... };
   return client.SendAsync(mediaRequest);
}

async Task<string> func()
{
    var response = await policy.ExecuteAsync(Send);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
tasks.Add(func());
```

However, on saying all this, you would likely want to use the more modern approach of adding Polly to the `IHttpClientFactory` implementation when you register the service via `AddPolicyHandler`, which will in turn take care of the request

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm confused about the last part though. Are you saying to replace method: Task<string> func() with Task<HttpResponseMessage> Send() ? I still need the task to return a string

Comment: @Ryn901 no, that method would still exist if you want to add the tasks to the list