# How to apply Polly retry for async POST with custom headers?

Tags: c#, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

I'm using a policy to retry a call in case it fails due to certain reason.

```
AsyncRetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetPolicy() => Policy
  .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(a => a.StatusCode is HttpStatusCode.Poof or ...)
  .WaitAndRetryAsync(stubborness, bideTime, 
    async (response, timespan, context) => { ... });
```

It performs just as expected for `GetAsync(...)`, `PostAsync(...)`, `PutAsync(...)`.

```
using HttpResponseMessage response = await RetryPolicy
  .ExecuteAsync(() => Client.PutAsync(url, content));
```

However, it doesn't work well with the general `SendAsync(...)`. In case the call fails, the retry kicks in **but** then crashes reporting an exception that the request already has been dispatched and can't be reused. While using the verb specific methods, a new request is constructed each time. Using the general one and passing a custom, pre-created request, will use it, hence stumbling. An important detail is that I need to alter the headers for each call.

```
    HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Put, new Uri(url));
    request.Content = new StringContent(GetJson(code), Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");
    request.Headers.Add("tenant", GetId(code));

    using HttpResponseMessage response = await RetryPolicy
        .ExecuteAsync(() => Client.SendAsync(request));
```

I have tried to provide the call specific header for each call while using the specialized methods. That failed as I haven't found any overload doing that.

I have tried altering default headers on the client for each call. That failed due to asunchronicity and wrong header being using during certain calls.

I have tried contructing a specialized client with the ID as a default header. That failed due to the gianormous number of different clients I'd end up with.

I have tried creating a new request and swoop it in to the retry. That failed because I haven't found a reference to the HTTP context nor the old request anywhere in the `WaitAndRetryAsync(...)` handler.

**Is there a way to dance around it?**

I've seen articles suggesting that `SendAsync(...)` isn't the most suitable choice if one needs to tampter with headers. However, I'm stubborn as duck and want to determine whether it's possible, not only if it's smoothly possible.

Comment: Polly's natural way of working with `HttpClient` is *within* the handlers. Is there some reason you're not doing it the natural way?

Comment: @StephenCleary The only reason for this approach is that we did a research and this seemed to be the examples we've found. So no, nothing technically specific. Could you elaborate on what you mean by *working within the handlers*? It's a bit fuzzy what it means in this specific case.

Comment: Like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) or [this](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory) or [this](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-using-polly-for-transient-fault-handling). The idea is to insert Polly as a delegating handler inside the `HttpClent` pipeline instead of having Polly wrap the `HttpClient` calls.

Comment: @StephenCleary I have tried the suggested approach and it leans towards working well, so it seems to resolve the issue I had. Fell free to post an answer to be accepted. That said, I haven't seen much discussions on the builder pattern being the natural way for Polly. I'm in no way objecting to your statement - only trying to grasp what makes it *natural*. Also, it's still unclear what to do if I get e.g. 500 in all the retries. Would the "natural" way be to throw?

Comment: Perhaps "natural" wasn't the best choice of wording. I meant an idea more like "built-in support". Regarding 500s, that's up to your policy. The default Polly policies for HttpClient do not retry 500s.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are calling `GetAsync`, `PostAsync` or `PutAsync` these methods are creating each and every time a new `HttpRequestMessage` whenever you call them.

On the other hand whenever you call `SendAsync` then you need to specify an `HttpRequestMessage` as a parameter. There are a lots of questions on StackOverflow which details why you can't reuse an `HttpRequestMessage` multiple times.

And that's basically the root cause of your problem. You want to reuse the same HRM for multiple retry attempts.

There are several workarounds:

- Copy the original `HttpRequestMessage` before you initiate a call ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761621/stream-was-already-consumed-error-using-polly-to-retry-requests-in-asp-net-cor/62764204#62764204))
- Have a method which creates a new `HttpRequestMessage` for each `SendAsync` call ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73541153/13268855), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73135460/13268855), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64626905/polly-handle-response-and-check-status-code/64627153#64627153))
- Place the retry inside a `DelegatingHandler` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835992/check-string-content-of-response-before-retrying-with-polly/73258058#73258058))

  - By the way that's what the `AddPolicyHandler` does ([1](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/DependencyInjection/PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L31), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988521/polly-retries-doesnt-close-existing-httpclient-call/73036620#73036620), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72208467/ihttpclient-polly-timeout-and-waitandretry-policy-when-handling-concurrent-http/72211805#72211805))